# How am I going to replicate this design with overlapping in the container?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

This is the sample of the design that I want to create.

[image]

I'm using scss for this build. Thank you. Because I'm not sure how am I going to get the height 100% for the image icon and overflow to the container? this is the snippet of the code.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 191px;
  height: 160px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background: url(${img}) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="url here" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this using css positions, flexbox, grids etc..

Using z-index you can move the item to foreground or background. See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Using positions:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 191px;
  height: 160px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
img{
max-width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#box1{
min-width: 80px;
height: 100%;
background: red;
position: absolute;
min-height: 200px;
top: -30px;
left: 30px;
z-index: -1;
}
#box2{
min-width: 80px;
height: 100%;
min-height: 200px;
background: blue;
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```